# How to get my node to only execute _process_physics when the game is NOT paused and never in the editor?

Tags: c++, godot

I have implemented a simple "rocket" in 2D, it accepts UP and DOWN for acceleration and left/right for rotation. The implementation looks like this:

```
void Player::_physics_process(double delta)
{
    UpdateMotionFromInput(delta);
    set_velocity(motion);
    set_rotation(rotation);
    move_and_slide();
}

void Player::UpdateMotionFromInput(double delta)
{
    const Input* i = Input::get_singleton();

    double delta_v = 0;
    if (i->is_action_pressed("ui_up"))
        delta_v += acceleration * delta;
    if (i->is_action_pressed("ui_down"))
        delta_v -= acceleration * delta;
    if (i->is_action_pressed("ui_left"))
        angular_velocity -= angular_acceleration * delta;
    if (i->is_action_pressed("ui_right"))
        angular_velocity += angular_acceleration * delta;

    constexpr float pi_factor = 360.0f / 3.14f;

    rotation += angular_velocity * delta;
    angular_velocity -= SIGN(angular_velocity) * angular_dampening * delta;

    Vector2 newVec(0, -delta_v);
    motion = motion + newVec.rotated((float)(rotation));
}
```

Now the problem is, this still works even in the editor - if I press the arrows the rocket will start flying around my editor. There's a Process option in the node component, but that does not really work for me, for the given options, I am getting these results:

1. When paused, Disabled - doesn't do anything ever.
2. Inherit, Pausable, Always - always executes `_process_physics`

I want to process physics when the game is run, not when I'm in editor. How can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you are aware, the Pause Mode lets you control when the code runs with respect to, well, the pause.

But that is not about whether the code runs in the editor... For that look for the property `editor_hint` of the `Engine` singleton. The getter is `is_editor_hint`, which will be `true` on the editor. You can check `editor_hint` during initialization, and then call `set_physics_process` with `true` or `false` if you want it to be able to run or not.